# How do I import a SAS layout file correctly in DSS?

Tags: data-science-studio

I'm trying to import a SAS layout file into DSS in such a way that I can use it as a lookup table for column names/descriptions. Is it possible to do this within Data Science Studio?

Here is a truncated example of the layout contents:

---

```
     DATE: 07/02/2014              POS RECORD LAYOUT                      PAGE: 1
                 Hospital, CATEGORY = "01" (SEE POSITIONS 3-4)

   SHORT DESCRIPTION                                LEN  START END    TYPE

   Provider Category Subtype Code                    2    1     2    VARCHAR2
     Description: Identifies the subtype of the provider, within the
                  primary category.  Used in reporting to show the
                  breakdown of provider categories, mainly for hospitals
                  and SNFs.
     SAS Name:    PRVDR_CTGRY_SBTYP_CD
     COBOL Name:  PRVDR-CTGRY-SBTYP-CD
     VALUES:      01=Short Term
                  02=Long Term
                  03=Religious Non-Medical Health Care Institutions
                  04=Psychiatric
```

Comment: Are you asking how to parse that text file into a data structure?  You should be able to write a SAS data step that would do it.

Comment: Info: This looks like the screen print from a "Data Dictionary". A "data dictionary" is a database of Fields, Files, Databases. In this case it is defining a field, it holds the values it can take and there meaning. "Data Dictionaries" can generate interface definitions in multiple languages (in this case Cobol and SAS) for the files / databases. "Data Dictionaries" are used on Mainframes.

Comment: There will be ways of exporting the data in a "Data Dictionary", talk to technical support

Comment: @wipa did you finally succeed to import the data? I am also trying to work with this pos file but have no clue!